# What is "Windows DIAL server" on Windows 10 Pro v2004?

Tags: windows, networking

I can see a network device on the network identified as some "Windows DIAL server". I know for sure this is just a regular PC runs Windows 10 Pro v2004
[image]

I suspect this is some new Windows service recently introduced, perhaps, Discovery and Launch (DIAL), which is a protocol co-developed by Netflix and YouTube (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discovery_and_Launch), but there is zero information about how to configure it on Windows systems.

Comment: Do you stream video?

Comment: no, not at all, streaming is disabled on this pc

Comment: See if this explains it>>>>>https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discovery_and_Launch

Comment: @Moab, do you know how to configure DIAL on windows?